# How to create a theme for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, themes, customization

I have a list of different images. I need to create a theme with these images.

I've seen `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` contains the installed themes, which contains a directory of images and a `*.theme` file.

So, how do I create a theme with a collection of images ?

Answer (score 0):

[First answer in google](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) discusses the windows .theme file format. If you are interested in further customisation of the windows shell, there's a huge community of modders who have developed custom shells, extensions. One of the more well-known ones is litestep, which has a long and interesting history. I've not tried it with windows 7 in particular, but remember having good results with it on earlier versions of windows.

There's more information on replacement shells on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell_replacement). I'm not sure what your final objective is, but hopefully you've got some info to go on now!